# Getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked Error when trying to run socket.io sample

Tags: node.js, sockets

While running the below socket.io sample,I'm getting the below error in the firebug.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1447667170745-0. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

My app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

My index.html :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the server listening port:

```
server.listen(8080);
```

Now that we will be using port 8080, change the HTML script to connect to that port:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

It should all work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Install cors library in your node js. Command to install cors is as below.

```
npm install cors
```

Now add below code to your nodejs server file to allow cross origin request allow.

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Sometime its necessary to keep your nodejs client file in root directory where your index file is.

Just check your firewall setting it also block the server port that you are using.

Hope it's work for you.